# How to tell if stock android media player is running

Tags: android, audio-player

I'm developing my first android app, and I am wondering if there is a way that I can tell if the stock android music player is running.

I am thinking there has to be a type of isRunning() boolean for it or something..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

AudioManager.[isMusicActive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29)?

Comment: Perfect, now I don't want to create an instance of AudioManager do I? If I want to check to see if any other apps are playing music, how would I go about that?

Comment: Come on don't be lazy! On top of API there is clear statement

"Use Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) to get an instance of this class."

Comment: Sorry for sounding lazy, but I'm a little confused. getting an instance of that class won't be able to tell me whether or not that service is running in another app will it?